Man who kisses the daughters of the boss of the branch office he's sent to close
I'm looking for a British TV show set in the 1930s maybe (?), only has a few episodes.
The man kisses all three of the manager's daughters in various charming British misunderstandings, once sitting on a ruined wall in the gardens of a mansion. In another scene, he paints a daughter in the nude. 
The first episode ends with him and one of the daughter's dancing the Charleston on an old steam train which the manager likes to drive around on. 
I saw the first episode of this years ago, it was really funny, I'd like to watch the whole thing but I don't know the name. 

Could it be Love on a Branch Line?

Civil Servant Jasper Pye has been denounced as boring by his
  girlfriend. He therefore decides to quit his job and to become an
  artist in Paris. His superiors have other ideas however, they decide
  that he is the perfect man to be sent to dismantle a government
  statistical research unit.
The unit is housed in a stately home and Jasper is soon distracted by
  the three daughters of owner Lord Flamborough. He finds himself cast
  headlong into the local lifestyle.


It sure is! Thanks heaps!
